# Custom Rails Validator Always Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a custom validator via rails, but my validator always creates the record but than fails the `save` check. Why ?

`customers_controller.rb`

```
@coupon = Coupon.create(user_unique_identifier: params[:UDID], promo_code: params[:code])
    unless !@coupon.save
     ##always fails here
```

`coupon.rb`

```
validate :one_per_customer, :before => :create

private
def one_per_customer
if self.is_paid_session
  return true
else
  @coupon = Coupon.where(user_unique_identifier: self.user_unique_identifier, promo_code: self.promo_code).first
  if @coupon.present?
    errors.add(:user_unique_identifier, 'PROMO CODE ALREADY APPLIED TO THIS DEVICE')
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Try removing `unless !@coupon.save` line.

Comment: Why use `unless !@coupon.save` instead of `if @coupon.save`?

Comment: I'll change to `@coupon.save` and try. I need to know if the line saves or not. This is for a mobile API

Comment: Try changing `@coupon = Coupon.create(user_unique_identifier: params[:UDID], promo_code: params[:code])` to `@coupon = Coupon.new(user_unique_identifier: params[:UDID], promo_code: params[:code])` and `unless !@coupon.save` to `if @coupon.save`.

Comment: Any luck with suggestions?

Comment: @Pavan I was thinking of changing to .new. Trying now !

Comment: @Pavan these still aren't working!

Comment: @Pavan it seems that the record is saving but is failing the .save line. Why would this happen? It seems it is being called twice

Comment: Did you changed `.create` to `.new`?

Comment: @Pavan yes. I think its getting called out of order somehow because its getting created but than returning that errror